# How to get mean in scatter plot using Geom_point in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I want to Add cluster point(mean point) of each GROUP and determine whether there is difference or not...

AB - Period 1 vs Period 2  (Continuous scale)

BA - Period 1 vs Period 2  (Continuous scale)

The code i used:

```
  ggplot(df , aes(x = Period_1_AB , y = Period_2_AB )) + 
  geom_point(pch = 0) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Period_1_BA , y = Period_2_BA), pch = 2)+
  geom_abline() + theme_update()
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(df)` in order to reproduce the chart.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help without the data but you can simply calculate the mean for each condition and save it in seperate a data.frame. Then you can use something like this:

```
  ggplot(df , aes(x = Period_1_AB , y = Period_2_AB )) + 
  geom_point(pch = 0) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Period_1_BA , y = Period_2_BA), pch = 2)+
  geom_point(data = df_mean, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_abline() + theme_update()
```

you can also add custom colour, size or characters here so that the mean is clearly visible.